# Node.js Request module not returning JSON in body

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

**SOLVED: encoding: 'utf8' needed to be set in the request.get options.**

Im attempting to load a JSON file with the Request module and I'm running into an issue. Here is the code:

```
request.get({url: url_obj.url, json: true}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        cb(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body.constructor);
        server_obj[url_obj.server] = body;

        cb(null, server_obj);
    }
});
```

'body' is coming back as a string even though I am specifying it should be json. Very strange. If I try JSON.parse(body) its coming back 'unexpected token'. JSLint is telling me that my JSON is 100% valid.

Here is the json. Its been edited a bit (just the string bits have been changed to keep some private data away)

```
{
    "build_info":  {
                       "build_version":  "v2.0.2.1",
                       "project_name":  "platformsc",
                       "jenkins_build_url":  "http://build03:8080/job/platformsc/1524/",
                       "git_commit_message":  "the last commit.",
                       "git_commit_id":  "c1b5dde6033977a8d183c7740ddad0f1f1589ce2",
                       "git_repo":  "git@gitlab.blahblahblah.lan:secrets/",
                       "git_commit_user":  "a developer",
                       "git_branch":  "name of branch"
                   }
}
```

Comment: The URL you are requesting is apparently not sending back valid JSON.

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick response. Ive gone ahead and run the JSON through a another couple validators and nothing has told me its invalid.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question and thought it said that it was invalid.  Can we see exactly with the response is and what the unexpected token is?  It seems like your response has more than you expect it to have.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.headers['content-type'])` show?

Comment: console.log(response.headers['content-type'] shows application/json